# How to edit dynamically ListBox items in VBA

Tags: excel, userform, listboxitem, vba

With ListBox1

```
.AddItem "OG Orders"
.AddItem "OG Sales"
.AddItem "GM"
.AddItem "GM% (YEF)"
.AddItem "GM% (Quarter)"
.AddItem "SFC"
.AddItem "SFC% (YEF)"
.AddItem "SFC% (Quarter)"
.AddItem "CM"
.AddItem "CM% (YEF)"
.AddItem "CM% (Quarter)"
```

End With

I have created this Listbox with following item. I want to remove some of the items dynamically depending on user selection. Is it possible? I have tried using IF loop, but it did not work.

Comment: Please show the code you used and what didn't work.

Comment: If Range("X23") = "Yes" Then
 
 
 With ListBox1

    .AddItem "Example1"
    .AddItem "Example2"
    .AddItem "Example3"
    .AddItem "Example4"

    
End With
Else

 With ListBox1

    .AddItem "Example1"
    .AddItem "Example2"

    
End With

End If

Comment: You can certainly remove items from the list, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23215070/4717755), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14751412/4717755), and [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27094).